# How to hover an image with a absolute href

Tags: css

I'm having some troubles to figure out how to make an hover to an image that have an absolute href link. I didn't want to put everything inside of the link. What i wanted to achive is when i mouseover the block the image change the state i.e a brightness filter or opacity.

**This is my html**

```
<li class="class--item class--item-1">
  <a href="#" class="class--link">Som text here</a>

  <div class="media__overlay media__img">
     <div class="img--class">
        <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="class-title">
           <h1 class="media__title">Some text here</h1>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

How can i select the img trougth the position: abosolute of the link? Can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Will the users try to click the image, thinking its part of the link?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, everything will be part of the link. Am i doing this in the wrong way? There is a better option?

Comment: That depends on your visual design, you can use that HTML as is and make the `li` a large, positioned block, and the `a` can be absolutely positioned to occupy all of the `li` with padding to accommodate the overlay... It can be done, but inserting everything that is clickable so that it's inside the `a` element would be easier/quicker, I think.

Comment: it's possible (see Lee Kowalkowski's answer), but it would have been easier to declare the hover on the parent element (the `li` in this case). Anyway, the `a` and img `div` belong to the same element, and would be cleaner to have a wrapper for the whole block, defined with a class

Comment: Hovering over the `li` will achieve the visual effect, but may deceive your users into thinking they're hovering the link.  The `li` and `a` element would need to be exactly the same size for it to be usable.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it .

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski i used to read that an `img` inside a `a` tag is not really correct even if it works, and that the way the OP does is supposed to be the good way, don't know if things have changed..

Comment: about the li hovering, i would expect as a user that all elements that interact with the hover to be clickable, but that's a debatable design topic i guess

Comment: Since HTML5 they relaxed the type of elements allowed inside an `a` element. @Kaddath  But `img` is inline so it has always been allowed, it's the `div` elements in between that would have been incorrect.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski haha i'll soon begin to feel old if this goes on :P old school at least, thx for the reminder, couldn't find the reference anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `IMG` with CSS when the link is being hovered:

```
a:hover + * img {
    /* properties to style the image, here */
}
```

The `IMG` is a descendant of the link's next sibling.

`+` is the next sibling selector (selects the next child of this element's parent).

`*` means 'any element, whatever it happens to be'.

The space separating `* img` means the `IMG` element inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```css
li img{
  opacity:0.6;
}
li:hover img{
  opacity:1;
}

li{
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:#eee;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<li class="class--item class--item-1"> 
<a href="#" class="class--link">Som text here</a>
 <div class="media__overlay media__img"> 
 <div class="img--class"> 
  <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="img"> 
  <div class="class-title"> 
   <h1 class="media__title">Some text here</h1> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
</li>
```

Comment: I did it but when i add the absolute position to the href it stop working. Thanks.